# Permission to rename organization in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, organization

I have bought a domain from Google Domains, call it example.com.

I have subscribed to G Suite basic and created an admin@example.com account to use on GCP instead of my personal account.

Inside GCP I found an organization already created named "example.com".

As admin@example.com, I tried to go to the settings of the IAM & Admin section of Google Cloud Platform. There I can see the name of the organization and its ID.

However, when I try to change  the name of the organization I get the following error message:

> You do not have the permission to rename this resource. Required
> permission(s): All of resourcemanager.organizations.get and
> resourcemanager.organizations.update

I tried to read the documentation on permissions but I couldn't find how to do this. How can I give myself permission to change the name of the organization?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org

Comment: What did you try so far to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Game myself "owner" permission, "project creator" permission, and other permissions but none of them allowed me to change the organization name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from GCP's console but you can from [G-Suite admin panel](https://admin.google.com).

You can find [here some more info how to change the name of the organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178186?hl=en) and go from there.